# swf file to just delete flash cookies

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, flash, actionscript, cookies

I'm trying to find a javascript method to delete flash cookies on a page, but with no luck.
I know it can be obviously done through flash or flex, but the problem is I know nothing about flash, flex and actionscripts...So my question is: Is there a way to just load a prebuilt flash movie in a page, which just programmatically deletes all the flash cookies it finds? Could any of you please make one for me? I could find some actionscript code around the internet and didn't look complex, but I don't know how to use it...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A Flash cookie or SharedObject is defined with a name & a path. In order to clear it, you must first retrieve it using those values.

```
var mySoName:String = "name of your sharedObject";
var mySoPath:String = "path to your sharedObject";
var mySo:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal(mySoName , mySoPath);
```

After this you can simply call the clear() method to delete its data , the reference still remains though.

```
mySo.clear();
```

If you don't know what the values are for name & path, I'm afraid I don't know how you can deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it's possible to delete ALL flash Shared Objects from a webpage.

The Flash sandboxing / security rules means that SOs aren't cross domain. This means that one site cannot poison or steal SOs for another site.

This (unfortunately for you) means that a site cannot delete ALL the SOs using Flash.

As far as I know, the only way to really remove all the SOs is to go do it yourself. (There's a few programs to manage / help you do this I believe)

There are global security settings which can block all new SOs from being created, but that doesn't (last time I looked) clear up the ones that already exist.

Comment: I wasn't clear, I knew of the security limitations, and all I want is to delete all the cookies on the domain of the page, that's enough for me ;) Thanks!